# Dimension and basis for the kernel and image of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $L : \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ with matrix $$ L_{\alpha}^{\beta}=\begin{pmatrix}
 4&2&1 \\
 0&1&3  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

with bases $\alpha=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$ and $\beta=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$

- Determine a basis and the dimension of $\ker{(L)}$ and Im$(L)$

So I was just wondering if what is I did is correct since the solution is different than what I found but with these kind of exercises there can be multiple correct solutions.

So to find a basis for the kernel of L, I tried to find the basis of the null space of the matrix $L_{\alpha}^{\beta}$. I first used the elementary row operation $R_{1} \to R_{1} - 2R_{2}$ which gives the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
 4&0&-5 \\
 0&1&3  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
we can then see that we have one independent variable so the dimension of the null space is $1$. I put everything in terms of that independent variable so I get $\left(\frac{5}{4}x_{3}, -3x_{3}, x_{3}\right)$. If I then substitute $x_{3}$ for $1$ I should have a basis for the null space. I then used the fact that the basis is also a basis for the kernel (I'm not sure if this is correct I asked chatGPT, but this isn't always correct) and so a possible basis for the kernel is then $\{(\frac{5}{4}, -3, 1)\}$.

To find a basis and dimension for the Im$(L)$ I used the dimension theorem to find the dimension of the image of L and so it's $2$. Then I said that since the dimension of Im$(L)$ is $2$ and the dimension of $\mathbb{R^2}$ is also $2$, that Im$(L) \cong \mathbb{R^2}$ and thus a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ is also a basis for Im$(L)$ and thus $\beta$ is a possible basis for Im$(L)$.

Now this is what I did, but now I'm wondering how they got the solution for a basis of the kernel to be $\{(-3, -8, 4)\}$ and a basis for the image of L $\{(4, 0),(3,1)\}$

Comment: Wait the fact that I used that Im$(L) \cong \mathbb{R^2}$ is it wrong because Im$(L) \to \mathbb{R^2}$ is not a linear map or is this wrong?

Comment: "*I should have a basis for the null space.  I then used the fact that the basis is also a basis for the kernel*"  Null space and kernel are two words for the same concept... they are the same thing...  "*I'm not sure if this is correct I asked chatGPT, but this isn't always correct*"  Don't ask chatGPT anything... it doesn't know anything, it doesn't understand anything.  It merely recognizes if you used "math words" and if so that it should respond with "more math words", but it can not understand which words specifically it should use or if it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Deliberately a partial answer**
I'm not tell you how they got their answer, because I'm not a mind-reader, but I am telling you why the answer you got is not the right one, although it's a step in the right direction.

---

I can't tell you how they determined a basis for the image, but your answer is also a correct one. So is $\{(1, 0), (0, 1) \}$.

For the kernel, you seem to have ignored this critical line in the problem statement:

"...with bases $\alpha=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$ and $\beta=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$"

Once you understand what that sentence-fragment tells you, you'll know how to convert your (correctly computed) list $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (
\frac{5}{4}, -3, 1)$ into an answer.

I'll just mention here that it'd be typical to write all those vectors as column vectors rather than as ordered-pairs or ordered-triples. I'm not sure it'd help clear up any confusion, but...it'll set you up well for other places where you see linear algebra applied.

Comment: I found it, thanks.